# jQuery / JavaScript Bubbling and stopPropagation doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, events, onclick

I'm making an edit button which pops up a modal box with a form to edit it. jQuery then sends this form to my server and I get a JSON response back. However, due to my bubbling issue, if I click on, for example, all of the edit buttons and then click on the last one and change a field, it does it across all of them.

```
$('.edit').click(function(event){
 //more code...
    modal_submit(the_id);
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

and then the submit event:

```
function modal_submit(the_id){
$('#modal form').submit(function(){
    //This will alert every time I have EVER clicked on an edit button
    alert(the_id);
    return false;
});
```

}

finally all of this is inside of a getScript:

```
$.getScript('js/edit.js',function(){
create_edit_btn();
```

});

I've only used this 1 other time, and it worked, but I also had to do this.event.stopPropagation, but if I do "this" now it says this.event is undefined, but like I said, this exact code worked before for another script I did.

Does anyone have any ideas? :\

EDIT:

```
the html is: 
<li> 
  <input id="item1" type="checkbox" value="webhosting|15" title="Web Hosting">  
    <p>Hosting for your web site</p>
</li>
```

Comment: I think your question is unclear.  Is the problem that your alert(the_id) is happening multiple times for each click of an edit button?  I'm not quite seeing how event propagation is an issue here, although seeing the html could help if that is actually the issue.

Comment: yes, it does an alert for each time .edit is clicked

Comment: the html is:
<li>        <input id="item1" type="checkbox" value="webhosting|15" title="Web Hosting">

        <p>Hosting for your web site</p></li>

Comment: wait, you tell it to alert every time a `.edit` is clicked. you call `modal_submit` which alerts the id. of course it happens every time one of them is clicked.

Comment: Your latest html should include also those form elements. The li you showing isn't really related to the code.

Comment: I don't think reutrn false works :\ I might be doing it wrong, but I'm just putting it at the end of my click event? Is that where you meant? Also, each ".edit" item is in a new <li>

Comment: @George IV I mean, if I click item1, item3, item2, then click submit on item4,  get an alert that says "1" then another that says "3" then another that says "2" etc. Is there anyway I can make it so it only sends the current ID not ALL of them again?

Comment: use jQuery's live function, and only set the handler once at the beginning. even before you create any .edit buttons if you want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An event can have multiple event listeners.  Each time you use $(element).submit(whateverFunction) you are adding another whateverFunction to the submit event.  If you only want only the last listener to be the action that is taken upon envoking the event, try doing this:

```
function modal_submit(the_id){

$('#modal form').unbind(); // this will remove all other event listeners from this element

$('#modal form').submit(function(){
        //This will alert every time I have EVER clicked on an edit button
        alert(the_id);
        return false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks! This seemed to do it. Live() didn't work neither did preventDefault(), but now it works like charm. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

I think you event.stoppropagation does its job already. It stopped all the bubbling on the click event of the button (ie, if you try checking the document body, it won't have mouse click event anymore). The reason why codes within submit of the form is still executed, is because this is called by the button's default action.

Together with event.stoppropagation(), I suggest you include this:

```
event.preventDefault();
```

So that the default action will not used and only the codes within your handler is executed.

Answer (score 0):

Is this in the function that creates edit buttons?

```
$('.edit').click(function(event){
 //more code...
        modal_submit(the_id);
        event.stopPropagation();
});
```

If it this, then it will add this handler multiple times to the same elements, causing a flurry of alerts. Use [`live`](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live#typefn), which will place the handler on every matched element, even if is is added later in execution.